# Not able to Call useCallback function on KeyDown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keyboard-events

```
            <span
              key="next"
              aria-label={"Next"}
              // ref={NextPageButtonRef}
              onClick={changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1)}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                    changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1);
                }
              }
              tabIndex={0}
            >
              <span>Next</span>
            </span>
```

```
 const changeHandler = useCallback(
    (exitEarly: boolean, target: number) => () => {
      if (target === page || exitEarly) {
        return;
      }

      onPageChange(clamp(target, 1, count as number));
    },
    [onPageChange, page, count]
  );
```

Actually I want to call "changeHandler" when Enter is pressed

It works when I call it directly like this

`onKeyDown = {changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1)}`

but I want it to only call when Enter is pressed

Comment: You should update your code like `onKeyDown={()=>changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `useCallback` has a function that returns a function. So when calling `changeHandler` in the `onKeyDown` handler it will not execute the function where you do the check and fire `onPageChange`

You can solve this by removing the extra function

```js
const changeHandler = useCallback(
    (exitEarly: boolean, target: number) => {
        if (target === page || exitEarly) {
            return;
        }

        onPageChange(clamp(target, 1, count as number));
    },
    [onPageChange, page, count],
);
```

Then the `onClick` need to have a anonymous function since the `changeHandler` does not return a function anymore it will invoke immediately.

```js
<span
  key="next"
  aria-label={"Next"}
  // ref={NextPageButtonRef}
  onClick={() => changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1)}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        changeHandler(!hasNext, page + 1);
    }
  }
  tabIndex={0}
>
  <span>Next</span>
</span>
```